# Android Spacing above recycler view on Lollipop

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have `FrameLayout` container which contains `fragments`.

`content_main.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.android.itea.MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main"
android:id="@+id/container">
</FrameLayout>
```

`activity_main.xml`

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/textColorWhite"
        app:itemIconTint="@android:color/white"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"
        app:itemBackground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"/>
       </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

While developing this app I've been testing it on moto x (4.4 KitKat). Today I tried to run the app on `5.1+` devices and noticed, that my screens with  `RecyclerView` have needless spacing, but when I use other fragments everything is fine.

**4.4 devices**: http://joxi.ru/YmEyGp7Haox0m6

**5.1 devices**: http://joxi.ru/RmzYNQlFJnLlrO

Any suggestions about the reason of that spacing?

**EDIT**

`layout` with `RecyclerView`

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/swipe_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.android.itea.fragments.EventsFragment">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" />
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Comment: Does the single_item.xml have any margins/padding? Or does the recyclerView have any margins/padding?

Comment: can you put recyclerView xml ?

Comment: @Amir yes. Look to the edited post

Comment: Removing **android:fitsSystemWindows** from SwipeRefreshLayout I think will fix your problem.

Comment: @Amir yeah! Now it's ok on both on 4,4 and 5.1+